# Set div height to fit to the browser using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs inside a container div, where I need to set them both to fit to the browser window like below, but it doesn't fit in my code, please suggest me a solution

[image]

My Style Sheet code

```
 html, body {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;         
 }
    
.container {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.div1 {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
}

.div2 {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Body

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `min-height`, [example](http://jsbin.com/aNICAva/1/edit)

Comment: If you need 100% height for both, why not set `height: 100%` for the `.container`?

Comment: OFF-TOPIC: what have you used to create that sketch?

Comment: @Victor Photoshop CS4

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Setting window full height for empty divs

1st solution with absolute positioning - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/4YxfL/)

```
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25%;
}
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 75%;
}
```

2nd solution with static (also can be used a relative) positioning & jQuery - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/zHsqD/)

```
.div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

$(function(){
  $('.div1, .div2').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('.div1, .div2').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 67):

You could also use [viewport percentages](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) if you don't care about old school IE.

`height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 4):

Man, try the min-height.

```
.div1 {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
}
.div2 {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare height of html to div1 elements together, like:

```
html,
body,
.container,
.div1,
.div2 {
    height:100%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ccham/

Comment: Dude, you dont HAVE to, but you can.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you need float.

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.div1, .div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div><!--
  --><div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

`display: inline-block;` is used to display blocks as inline (just like spans but keeping the block effect)

Comments in the html is used because you have 75% + 25% = 100%. The space in-between the divs counts (so you have 75% + 1%? + 25% = 101%, meaning line break)

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest way is to use grid system with fractions.
So your container have 100vw, which is 100% of the window width and 100vh which is 100% of the window height.

Using fractions or 'fr' you can choose the width you like. the sum of the fractions equals to 100%, in this example 4fr. So the first part will be 1fr (25%) and the seconf is 3fr (75%)

More about fr units [here](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/).

```css
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

/*You don't need this*/
.div1{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.div2{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='div1'>This is div 1</div>
  <div class='div2'>This is div 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a brief explanation of your code.

Comment: I added an explanation now, I hope it's clear. Thanks!