# Ensure div takes up entire viewport

Tags: html, css

First off, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pesLL8f/) that represents the issue.

I am trying to have a "container" id that is the size of the entire viewport. This is so all `div` items in `#container` fit inside the page without scrolling. I assumed thats what `height: 100%` in `html`, `body`, and `#container` would do.

It seems though, that the `.thirdwidth` elements height is that of the full viewport, and is not just expanding to the bottom of the `#container` div (if you inspect the element, it appears that the `.thirdwitdh` elements go outside the `#container`)

Does anybody know why this is happening? I would like to be able to have all Sections 0-3 fit on the page without scrolling.

Comment: If it is a static site, give a trial and error method to find the exact size of your screen. But this will affect the scroll in other screen resolutions!

Comment: Check this out [SIMILAR QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934141/set-div-height-to-fit-to-the-browser-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve `100% viewport` height you can try `100vh`, but why are you placing it's position to absolute.

```
    body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: what is `vh` for the height property?

Comment: @GSURENDARTHINA: `viewport's height` and **vw** for `viewport's width`

Comment: @GSURENDARTHINA that's viewport height.

Comment: How is that different from em?

Comment: @GSURENDARTHINA i think `1em` is equals `16px`,  a unit in the field of typography. credits:google.com

Comment: @frnt I edited the fiddle to have `position: relative;`, the changes to `body`, and the use of `100vh` in the `#container` css. It still seems to require that I scroll for  the entire Sections 1-3 to be in view. Is there something else I need to change?

https://jsfiddle.net/0pesLL8f/1/

Comment: @ClayBenson That's what you want.

Comment: @frnt, did you see my updated fiddle? I am trying to avoid having a scrollbar at all (the section columns should end at the bottom of the viewport, but they still require scrolling)

Comment: @ClayBenson i think you have scroll bec. u have a `#gameinfo` elem which is *20%* above the `thirdwidth` elem which is 100vh, that makes them 120%/vh in total. try making the `thirdwidth: 80vh` maybe?

Comment: @frnt That seems to work in a way! The only thing is I think the div really is extending past the screen, its just being hidden from the user (thats why the section titles don't quite appear to be in the center, as some of the div is being cut off). Do you know if it can be done without hiding overflow? Maybe I should post a separate question

Comment: @Abbr wow! That actually did it. I can split up section 0 and sections 1-3 into a 20/80 and then do it that way. Thanks!

Comment: 20+80 and that makes them 100% of your current viewport. anytime

Comment: It will as you want your #container to be fixed from x and y position. So internal parts you need to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Abbr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858627/abbr) for this answer (thought I would post a standalone answer so it's not hidden within the comments)

Due to the fact that the `gameinfo` id is 20% of the parent div, setting the `.thirdwidth` columns to 100% height made the entire page 120%

Changing the `height` of the `.thirdwidth` in my CSS to 80% fixed it!